# Streamlit how to add delete button to right side of every row in dataframe

Tags: python, streamlit, large-language-model

I am working on streamlit application where after running the code, streamlit app opens and dataframe appears. Now, I want to delete button after every row in the dataframe. Is there any way we can create delete  button after every row. Please suggest.

I've tried converting the dataframe into table but that is also not possible. Please suggest a way,